# CodeEval Overlapping Rectangles code review

Tags: java

I have been testing my code for the [overlapping rectangles](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/70/) challenge on codeeval. I feel my code is close to the solution as I have tested it on my machine and it appears correct. Codeeval is picky however and won't execute the code, claiming it is hanging.No further information is given. It has done this in the past but that was due to me not closing my scanner at the end. Am I violating a similar principle here?

Any recommendations on finding the solution simpler or better coding practices is appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/minda_000/Desktop/text.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);
    scan.useDelimiter(",");
    boolean flag = true;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        Scanner scanline = new Scanner(line);
        scanline.useDelimiter(",");
        int lxa = scanline.nextInt();
        int lya = scanline.nextInt();
        int rxa = scanline.nextInt();
        int rya = scanline.nextInt();
        int lxb = scanline.nextInt();
        int lyb = scanline.nextInt();
        int rxb = scanline.nextInt();
        int ryb = scanline.nextInt();
        int[] contentsofx = contentsOfX(lxa, rxa);
        int[] contentsofy = contentsOfY(lya, rya);
        int[] contentsofx2 = contentsOfX(lxb, rxb);
        int[] contentsofy2 = contentsOfY(lyb, ryb);
        scanline.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < contentsofx.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < contentsofx2.length; j++) {
                if (contentsofx[i] == contentsofx2[j]) {
                    if(i<contentsofy.length && i<contentsofy2.length && contentsofy[i]==contentsofy2[j]){
                        System.out.println(true);
                        flag=false;

                    }
                }

            }
        } 
    if(flag)    {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
                flag=true;

    }

    scan.close();

}


public static int[] contentsOfX(int lx, int rx) {

    int[] line = new int[(rx - lx)];
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        line[i] = lx + i;
    }
    return line;

}

public static int[] contentsOfY(int ly, int ry) {

    int[] line = new int[(ly - ry)];
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        line[i] = ry + i;
    }
    return line;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, you are changing "C:/Users/minda_000/Desktop/text.txt" to args[0] before uploading your solution to CodeEval, right?

Some of the other issues:

You're outputting True and False in lowercase when they're supposed to be capitalized.

In this line --

```
if(i<contentsofy.length && i<contentsofy2.length && contentsofy[i]==contentsofy2[j]){
```

-- you've got a problem when i and/or j are larger than the lengths of contentsofy and contentsofy2.

And comments would make your code easier to read. :-)

Comment: Yes I think the problem has something to do with Scanner or perhaps an edge case solution where my code finds itself in an infinite loop.

Comment: Good catches. Thanks for your help, I ended up scraping this code as I figured out an easier implementation all together. I made some bad assumptions with this code so I don't even know if the nested for loops would work even considering your changes. I can see an implementation that'd fix it but it's far more complicated than my other solution so maybe it's not worth exploring. I'll add more comments in my future challenges, thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I know what it's like to get into that kind of situation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped this code and started over more or less with a much cleaner solution just using boolean logic. The problems with this code is the contentsOfX and contentsOfY methods should be 1 size greater for one point overlap. Additionally, at this time I implied one rectangle would always be to the left of the other. The nested for loop does not work as intended because of this. Still the arrays are sorted for each value from minimum value of x,y to maximum value of x,y so if you check for the reverse polarity index within the array as well the logic should be the work.